# How to extract IP and URL from a log file

Tags: shell, grep, logs

I have a long and generic squid log file. My boss is asking me to extract IP's alongside with accessed URLs. So far I can process IP's, but I need those IP's listed with the URLs accessed.

Something like:

```
172.10.1.20 http://url1.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Normally squid logs has IP's on 3rd field and access URL's on 7th field of log file, if it is different in your system then adjust number accordingly.

using `awk`,

```
awk '{print $3 " " $7}' logfile
```

using `cut`,

```
cut -d' ' -f3,7 logfile
```